# How to force Chromium download dialog without file being ready

Tags: c#, .net, chromium, .net-core-3.1

I want to send text file to user while the data is being processed. The user is being notified that the file will start downloading within few minutes but as we know user knows better and after about half a minute they refresh and try again.

Chromium browsers will not show download dialog until the file is ready (big data export) which can take up to 3 minutes.
Meanwhile Firefox notifies the user straight away.

Is there a way to trick Chromium browsers into showing download dialog sooner?

**EDIT:** I do not have control over frontend (3rd party company)

Example code:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Download()
{
  Response.Headers.Add("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=test.txt");
  Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
  await Response.StartAsync();

  await Response.WriteAsync("Hello World!");//Firefox shows that a file is downloading after this line
  //await Response.Body.FlushAsync();

  await Task.Delay(10000); //10s long operation

  return new EmptyResult();//Chromium browsers show the download dialog somewhere after this line
}
```

Comment: You can't with HTTP Request.  Connection closes after each Request/Response.  FireFox is not using HTTP.  They could be using HTTP over TCP.  TCP will keep connection open.  Or they may be using a WepSocket which is HTTP but keeps connection open after each Request/Response.

Comment: you could do this as an async thing - show the download button when the process is actually complete

Comment: With `fetch` you can poll the server (every x seconds), if it's ready and when it is, start the download. You might even show a progress bar this way - that will help users to wait.

Comment: Sadly I don't have control over frontend. Owned by another company

Comment: You say 5 minutes. That should timeout all requests unless you actually send some data (in chunks).

Comment: It is quite unclear what kind of help you are looking for here - if you can't change server-side code ("I don't have control over frontend") it sounds like your only option is to find some setting in Chrome/others browsers to change the behavior.... but that obviously not an SO question. Could you please [edit] the post to clarify what you hope to see as an answer?

Comment: I have control over server side code but not fronted ( UI ) so I can't implement a system where users first request the file then download.

So my only option right now, until the third party company responsible for UI will start working on this (about 3-6 months), is to somehow force Chrome to display file download dialog.

And timeouts are not an issue as data is being sent in chunks